# React Testing Library toBeInTheDocument failing despite being in the DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a test which basically contains the following code:

```js
    const row = await screen.findByText('Test Subject');

    try {
      expect(row).toBeInTheDocument();
    } catch (e) {
      screen.debug();
      throw e;
    }
```

The debug is for trying to track this down. `findByText` succeeds, and does find the element. I can log this out, and it appears. But when I do the expect, it fails **SOMETIMES**. It's unpredictable. I'm pretty certain the DOM isn't changing between calls, as I have logs out on every render and nothing logs out between the find and the assert.

I won't print the whole DOM tree, but on the catch debug, I can clearly see the row.

```html
<tr
                  class="sc-jgrIVw bDPrDC"
                >
                  <td
                    class="sc-jeqYYF hinrdE"
                  >
                    <div
                      class="sc-clIAKW jvtlES"
                    >
                      05-Dec-2022 12:08
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td
                    class="sc-jeqYYF ijUrhn"
                  >
                    <div
                      class="sc-clIAKW jvtlES"
                    >
                      <div
                        title="Test"
                      >
                        Test 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td
                    class="sc-jeqYYF ijUrhn"
                  >
                    <div
                      class="sc-clIAKW jvtlES"
                    >
                      Test Subject
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

So as far as I can tell, RTL knows my DOM is there, the DOM log shows its there, but `toBeInTheDocument` throws. What could I be missing?

Comment: Sounds like a timeout issue maybe? Default timeout is 1000ms, have you tried setting it a bit higher?

Comment: A timeout on what? I've gotten no reports from jest, and the `findBy..` works. It gets the DOM element. I can log it out, get the info, etc.

Comment: You get all of this even in the cases when `expect` throws afterwards?

Comment: Yeah, no timeouts. I've modified the code from the actual code i'm working with due to privacy, but it's not just this one scenario. Sometimes it'll fail, sometimes it won't. When it fails, I get `    element could not be found in the document`

Comment: Umm, that's weird. I know this is not recommended at all and is basically the same but can you try using `waitFor` and `getByText` instead?

Comment: I replaced all the `findBy` with `getBy` as i've added an additional assertion. it is a table, and the code in the OP is the first assert, to check that the data loaded and rendered. i'm now asserting on table rows to be X number and using `getBy` everywhere and it's not doing it any more (currently, its random so who knows..), but the issue still kinda persists that this doesnt make much sense and shouldnt happen. not much confidence in these tests right now

Comment: You can try to queryByText and instead of checking if toBeInTheDocument() you can check to expect(row).not.toBeNull().

Comment: I could but it kinda feels like just hacking it and i lose confidence in the test which is against the whole point.